# mount.cifs gives me "mount error: cifs filesystem not supported by the system"

Tags: mount, samba, cifs, modprobe

i try to mount a OneDrive Folder to my Linuxserver. However, as i try mout.cifs with XXX beeing the correct values...

```
root@XXX:~# mount.cifs //onedrive.live.com/about/en-us/signin/ /usr/plex/share -o user='XXX',password='XXX'
```

...it returns:

```
mount error: cifs filesystem not supported by the system
mount error(19): No such device
```

I installed cifs-utils without any errors. (version 2:6.8-1)

My dear friend google lead me to some websites telling me to check some things:

1.

```
zgrep -i cifs /proc/config.gz
```

returns nothing.

2.

```
modprobe cifs
```

returns:

```
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:514 lookup_builtin_file() could not open builtin file '/lib/modules/4.15.0/modules.builtin.bin'
modprobe: FATAL: Module cifs not found in directory /lib/modules/4.15.0
```

3.

I tried updating packages, reinstalling cifs-utils, upgrading the kernel, rebooting and recompiling the kernel. Nothing worked for me.

4.

```
uname -r
```

returns:

```
4.15.0
```

5.

```
lsb_release -a
```

returns:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

6.
the samba-service is up and running.

```
service smbd status
```

returns

```
● smbd.service - Samba SMB Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/smbd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2019-02-03 05:19:03 CET; 29min ago
     Docs: man:smbd(8)
           man:samba(7)
           man:smb.conf(5)
 Main PID: 561 (smbd)
   Status: "smbd: ready to serve connections..."
    Tasks: 5 (limit: 165)
   CGroup: /system.slice/smbd.service
           ├─ 561 /usr/sbin/smbd --foreground --no-process-group
           ├─ 662 /usr/sbin/smbd --foreground --no-process-group
           ├─ 664 /usr/sbin/smbd --foreground --no-process-group
           ├─ 768 /usr/sbin/smbd --foreground --no-process-group
           └─1570 /usr/sbin/smbd --foreground --no-process-group

Feb 03 05:46:52 XXX.net smbd[2050]: pam_unix(samba:session): session closed for user nobody
Feb 03 05:46:52 XXX.net smbd[2052]: pam_unix(samba:session): session closed for user nobody
Feb 03 05:46:53 XXX.net smbd[2054]: pam_unix(samba:session): session closed for user nobody
Feb 03 05:46:56 XXX.net smbd[2055]: pam_unix(samba:session): session closed for user nobody
Feb 03 05:46:56 XXX.net smbd[2056]: pam_unix(samba:session): session closed for user nobody
Feb 03 05:46:58 XXX.net smbd[2057]: pam_unix(samba:session): session closed for user nobody
Feb 03 05:47:11 XXX.net smbd[2059]: pam_unix(samba:session): session closed for user nobody
Feb 03 05:47:15 XXX.net smbd[2064]: pam_unix(samba:session): session closed for user nobody
Feb 03 05:48:15 XXX.net smbd[2073]: pam_unix(samba:session): session closed for user nobody
Feb 03 05:48:20 XXX.net smbd[2076]: pam_unix(samba:session): session closed for user nobody
```

However, the last lines seem a bit strange to me.

So finally, i am left with no idear. I searched the web for hours but the only soloution i could find was recompilling the kernel. Obvoiusly that did not work for me.

I hope someone can help me. If you need more information, please give me the exact command line as i am relatively new to linux.

Thank you in advance!

Greeting
Smallmountains

PS: Please excuse my bad english. Thanks.

--------UPDATE----------

The command

```
find /lib/modules/ -name cifs.ko
```

returs a buch of kernal names:

```
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1019-aws/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1036-azure/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1019-kvm/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-33-lowlatency/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1019-azure/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1011-aws/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-38-lowlatency/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1009-azure/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1022-azure/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1006-gcp/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1021-kvm/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1008-gcp/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1012-oem/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1023-kvm/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1025-kvm/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1024-oem/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-39-lowlatency/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-42-generic/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1020-aws/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-43-lowlatency/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1025-gcp/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-23-lowlatency/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1008-kvm/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1012-kvm/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1028-kvm/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1004-oem/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1031-azure/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1023-azure/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1025-azure/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-30-generic/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1027-kvm/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1009-aws/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1028-azure/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1024-gcp/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1015-oem/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1016-aws/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-32-generic/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1029-aws/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-33-generic/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1030-azure/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1017-aws/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1023-gcp/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1018-gcp/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1035-azure/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1007-aws/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-29-generic/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1012-azure/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1009-oem/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1021-azure/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1006-oem/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1021-gcp/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1014-gcp/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1028-oem/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1015-gcp/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-32-lowlatency/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1017-kvm/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-36-generic/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1026-oem/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1013-oem/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1021-oem/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1027-aws/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-23-generic/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1010-aws/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1021-aws/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1019-gcp/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1017-gcp/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-36-lowlatency/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1010-gcp/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1018-azure/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1011-kvm/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-29-lowlatency/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1007-oracle/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-38-generic/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-39-generic/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1031-aws/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1032-azure/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-20-generic/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1020-kvm/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1008-oem/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1010-kvm/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1014-azure/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-42-lowlatency/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1030-oem/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-24-lowlatency/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-43-generic/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1016-kvm/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-30-lowlatency/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-34-lowlatency/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-24-generic/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1018-oem/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-22-lowlatency/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1025-aws/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1023-aws/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-20-lowlatency/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1009-gcp/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-34-generic/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1026-kvm/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1026-gcp/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1017-oem/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-1013-azure/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
```

Which one should i choose? And do i use the....

```
GRUB_DEFAULT='Example GNU/Linux distribution'
```

...in the file...

```
/etc/default/grub
```

to choose what kernal to boot into? Remember, i do have acces to the server only via ssh after the boot process ist sucessfull. I cannot choose a kernal during boot on a screen.

Thank you in advance.
Greetings: Smallmountain

Answer (score 2):

You are not running the kernel shipped with ubuntu:

```
uname -r
returns:

4.15.0
```

It should have been `4.15.0-45-generic` in current ubuntu 18.04.

Run this to find out which installed kernels have the `cifs.ko` module on your system, and reboot into that kernel: `find /lib/modules/ -name cifs.ko`.

On my 18.04 system, for example:

```
root@nsnx:~# uname -r
4.15.0-45-generic
root@nsnx:~# find /lib/modules/ -name cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-44-generic/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-45-generic/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
```

If you do see a `cifs.ko` module for your custom `4.15.0` kernel, maybe all you need to do is run `depmod -a`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your aswer! I updeated the aswer, so i could print the result of the "find /lib/modules/ -name cifs.ko".

Answer (score -2):

your Ubuntu can not find cifs in filesystem. it is not necessary to add cifs.ko to kernel. you can dreat it in menuconfig in kernel und choose cifs in filesystem. after that copy the new zImage

Comment: We still need to compile the kernel for that though, right? I think this answer needs a lot more detail. New users won't be aware of the context of menuconfig

Comment: for new zImage is a make on Host necessary